# Aurelia BindingEngine propertyObserver does not fire

Tags: javascript, file-upload, aurelia

I have an Aurelia file upload controller where I would like to observe the `progress` property of any object that is added to the array `uploadedFiles`. First off, my HTML template looks like this:

```
<input type="file" name="files" files.bind="fileList" multiple change.delegate="fileSelected($event)" />
```

This is the controller (simplified). The method `fileSelected` gets fired when the user selects a file.

```
import {BindingEngine, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpService} from '../../services/http-service';
import {UploadedFile} from '../../models/uploaded-file';

@inject(BindingEngine)
export class FileUploader {
  httpClient: HttpService;
  fileList: FileList;
  uploadedFiles: UploadedFile[];

  constructor(bindingEngine) {
    this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
    this.httpClient = new HttpService();
    this.uploadedFiles = [];
  }

  fileSelected(): void {
    if (this.fileList) {
      // Convert the FileList object into an array of UploadedFile objects because the Aurelia template engine cannot iterate over a 'FileList' object with 'repeat.for'.
      for (let i = 0; i < this.fileList.length; i++) {
        let file = this.fileList.item(i);
        let uploadedFile = new UploadedFile();
        uploadedFile.file = file;

        // Subscribe to changes of the 'progress' property of every UploadedFile.
        uploadedFile.subscription = this.bindingEngine
          .propertyObserver(uploadedFile, 'progress')
          .subscribe((newValue, oldValue) => {
            console.log('Progress changed from ' + oldValue + ' to ' + newValue);
          });

        this.uploadedFiles.push(uploadedFile);

        // Start off the file upload itself.
        this.httpClient.uploadRequest('files', file, uploadedFile.updateProgress)
          .then((httpResponse) => {
            // File uploaded successfully!
          });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I do this because the progress update comes from an external event and therefore the binding from the controller back to the template does not work out of the box (because not every object is observed for performance reasons).

Here's the `UploadedFile` class:

```
export class UploadedFile {
  file: File;
  uploaded: boolean;
  totalBytes: number;
  uploadedBytes: number;
  progress: number;
  subscription: any;

  constructor() {
    this.uploaded = false;
    this.progress = 0;
  }

  updateProgress(event: ProgressEvent) {
    this.totalBytes = event.total;
    this.uploadedBytes = event.loaded;

    this.progress = this.uploadedBytes / this.totalBytes * 100;
    console.log('Progress is ' + this.progress + ' %.');
  }
}
```

Here's what the upload request looks like (note the `withProgressCallback` line):

```
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';

export class HttpService {
  backendUrl: string;
  httpClient: HttpClient;

  constructor() {
    // ...
  }

  uploadRequest(url: string, file: File, progressCallback: any): Promise<any> {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    return this.httpClient.createRequest(url)
      .asPost()
      .withContent(formData)
      .withCredentials(true)
      .withProgressCallback(progressCallback) // This adds the progress callback.
      .send();
  }
}
```

Now there is obviously something I'm doing wrong, because the property change event never fires, even though I can see the progress updates in the browser console in the `UploadedFile` class.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the `propertyObserver` subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to upload progress, you need to ensure it's trackable by browser. Secondly, your `uploadRequest` in `HttpService` doesn't preserve execution context, which means `updateProgress` won't be called on correct instances of `UploadedFile` class. Probably you need to do something like this:

```javascript
this.httpClient.uploadRequest('files', file, () => uploadedFile.updateProgress() })
      .then((httpResponse) => {
        // File uploaded successfully!
      });
```

Comment: That's it, the closure was executed in the `XMLHttpRequest` object instead of the `UploadedFile` context, that's why the `progress` property was not set in the `UploadedFile`. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, I found out that I don't even need the property observer in that case, the property is observed automatically by Aurelia.